# How to wait until no more "404" is coming from weblient in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, http-status-code-404, webclient

I need to download a large file (about 3-5GB) in my application. The file is generated dynamically on request, so i can't predict, when it is ready for download. I need to try the download, and when i get a 404, i have to wait and retry later.

The download is async because i have a progressbar.
I tried also to put a "normal" download (WC.DownloadFile(...)) in a try..catch, but didn't solve my problem.

```
Private Sub DownloadUpdate()
    Dim RndName As String = IO.Path.GetRandomFileName
    UpdateTmpPath = IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, RndName)).FullName
    UpdateTmpFile = UpdateTmpPath & "\update.zip"
    UpdateUnzipDir = IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(UpdateTmpPath & "\update").FullName
    Log(UpdateTmpFile)
    WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(url), UpdateTmpFile)
End Sub
```

btw sorry for my english, it's not my first language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :)
By adding the handler "DownloadFileCompleted" i'm able to check the Http-Status:

```
    Private Sub AfterDownload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Object) Handles WC.DownloadFileCompleted
    Dim status As HttpStatusCode = DirectCast(CType(e.Error, WebException).Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode

    If status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
        "...wait and retry download"
    Else
        "...do something with downloaded file"
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps someone.

Daniel